How to inherit from pandas dataframe class and instantiate with a filepath
I would like to create a class that inherits from the pandas dataframe. I want to instantiate the object with a csv file path, but keep getting errors. I found this post: Use read_csv from pandas to create an instance of a child class of pandas.DataFrame in Python, which is very similar, but requires reading the csv first and then wrapping the object around it, however, I want to essentially do it in one line, something more like the following:
class my_class(pd.DataFrame):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls)
        
    def __init__(self, save_path):
        self.save_path = save_path
        self.__new__(pd.read_csv(save_path))

    def my_func(self):
        print('New function!')

save_path = 'test_my_class.csv'

pd.DataFrame({'test_col': [1,2,3]}).to_csv(save_path)

mc = my_class(save_path)

I've tried this as well as a few other variations, but keep getting maximum recursion errors, I believe from cyclical calls of new and init.
Thanks for your help!

This should fix your code:
import pandas as pd

save_path = 'test.csv'
pd.DataFrame({'test_col': [1,2,3]}).to_csv(save_path)

class my_class(pd.DataFrame):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls)
        
    def __init__(self, save_path):
        super().__init__(pd.read_csv(save_path))
        self.save_path = save_path
        
    def my_func(self):
        print('New function!')

mc = my_class(save_path)

mc.my_func()
mc.head()

You can actually drop the __ new__ implementation, it is not required. When I run your code I also get the max recursion error at the end, however you have scroll to the middle of the traceback stack to get what is wrong:

If you go to the github repo for pandas you will see that _mgr is a private attribute of the DataFrame class which has no default value. Hence, when you inherit Dataframe you are also inherit this attibute (and many more) which you have to set somewhere or your code will break.
So unless you do that manually ("by copying the __ init__" code from the actual implementation), you must call the __ init__ function from your parent class (DataFrame) to deal with this.
